# CRON Job Send email to users in DB?

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron

If I've got a database of users that have filled out a form, can I use a cron job to send an automated email? If so, what is the best way to "loop" it so that it sends the email once to each user?

```
$data = mysql_query("
SELECT *
FROM completed
WHERE
followupsent='0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND valuesent + INTERVAL 4 DAY <= NOW()
")
or die(mysql_error()); 

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{
}
```

This checks to see if "followupsent" has been updated already as it updates with `NOW()` when it sends and also checks to see how many days since the value was sent.

I'm worried that by putting the email sending information in the while tags is going to loop for each row and end up sending a ton of emails.

Would using and `if` instead of a `while`:

```
if($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{
}
```

In order to send out to the first in the database and then let the cron job handle the rest by checking every minute which one is next?

Comment: You could always send a *single* mail with all the recipients blind-copied.

Comment: Hi, hmmm I don't really understand what is the problem for you to send an email for each user in a while while getting values from your table,

You don't want to send 1000 email in 30seconds ?

And yes, you could do what @eggyal said

Comment: @eggyal There are specific details called from the database that relate to each user so a BCC wouldn't work as it sends the same email.

Comment: Fair enough.  So then, as @user3742755 has asked, what is your concern with sending separate emails from within the `while` loop?

Comment: @user3742755 I read that using the while loop if you've got 500 users all waiting for an email the CRON job will run, and attempt to send the emails, but before it updates the database, it runs again, thus sending the email multiple times...?

Answer (score 0):

Thats a perfectly fine way to do it. It will only send it it once per record (so assuming you have no duplicates in your completed table).

I assume you are updating the valuesent field in the loop

Comment: That's correct. My main worry is that it will attempt to send 500 emails, won't update, then the cron job will run again and attempt to send another 500 emails to the same people?

Comment: Well sure, maybe if there is an error in your update query. Obviously test it first. But you would have the same issue regardless if you do it all in one go vs doing 1 at a time.

Comment: but if the CRON Job only runs one email at a time, then it would move on to the next row and the mailing would have completed. If the CRON Job starts, but the while loop doesn't complete and update the rows that haven't been done, it'll then attempt to send to all those rows again? Then again and again?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

1. You ensure that your `completed` table uses a transactional storage engine, e.g. InnoDB:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE completed ENGINE=InnoDB;
   ```
2. You define a new `BOOLEAN` column that indicates (to any other database connections) that a given record is in the process of being updated:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE completed ADD COLUMN updating BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE;
   ```
3. You use a [locking read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) to `SELECT` the records that are to be emailed, followed within *the same transaction* by an `UPDATE` to the newly created column.  For example, using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php):

   ```php
   $dbh->beginTransaction();

   $select = $dbh->query('
     SELECT *
     FROM   completed
     WHERE  followupsent IS NULL
        AND valuesent <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 4 DAY
        AND NOT updating
     FOR UPDATE
   ');

   $dbh->exec('
     UPDATE completed
     SET    updating = TRUE
     WHERE  followupsent IS NULL
        AND valuesent <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 4 DAY
        AND NOT updating
   ');

   $dbh->commit();
   ```
4. You can then update the database (removing the `updating` flag, together with whatever other status you require) as each email is sent:

   ```php
   $success = $dbh->prepare('
     UPDATE completed
     SET    followupsent = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            updating = FALSE
     WHERE  id = ?
   ');

   $failure = $dbh->prepare('
     UPDATE completed
     SET    updating = FALSE
     WHERE  id = ?
   ');

   foreach ($select as $row) {
     $command = mail(...) ? $success : $failure;
     $command->exec(array($row['id']));
   }
   ```

Note that if the script terminates prematurely, the database may be left in an undesirable state—i.e. records may have `updating=TRUE` but there is no longer any script that is processing them; this could lead to some records not being emailed *at all*.  You may want to guard against this eventuality by [registering a custom shutdown function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php), or else by periodically inspecting the database for such "orphaned" records (however you must of course be sure that they are not currently being processed by a running script).

Comment: Just trying this out now, i've never used PDO and use MySQL or MySQLi, when you're calling $dbh->exec/prepare etc, is that basically just PDO connecting to the database? EDIT: Looking at it, I have no idea how to translate it in to MySQL. I have never seen the FOR UPDATE tag at the end of a SELECT. Does that work in MySQL? What does it do? Cheers

Comment: @BN83: Follow the links in my answer.  They explain it all better than I can.